# What is the kernel of the operator $f \mapsto xf$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

While analyzing an operator corresponding to a term in a PDE, I ran into a curiosity that I'm not totally sure about. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded subset and the operator $A : L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ be defined by $f \mapsto xf$ for any $x \in \Omega$. This would be the case if we have the term $xf(x)$ appear in the PDE for all $x \in \Omega$. How would you describe the kernel of $A$, and does the coefficient $x$ matter? Is this operator naively defined in that we would need to fix the coefficient $x \in \Omega$ first, in which case we would have an uncountable amount of these operators?

My attempt is to suppose $f \in \text{dom}(A)$ is such that $Af = xf = 0$. Then this holds when $f = 0$, but also when $x=0$. This originally made me think that the kernel of $A$ is something like $\{f=0 ~ \text{a.e.}\} \cap \{x=0\}$. However, since only $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ is being mapped by $A$, I suppose the kernel of $A$ is just $\{f=0 ~ \text{a.e.}\}$.

Comment: You're mapping things into $L^2$, so you don't care what they are at points (actually it's worse than that, you can't tell what they are at points). The kernel will be all of the functions such that xf is almost everywhere 0. So it'll be something like all of the functions whose kernel is a set of full measure (since as you noted the x isn't doing anything except at the point 0 which is null).

Comment: You need to be careful with your spaces and maps here, in the end you aro essentially considering an action map of a ring on a module which means that the kernel will be the annihilator of x, depending on the properties of your ring and your choice of x a lot can happen.

Comment: @paulgarrett What do you mean by stabilize $L^2$? Wouldn't the operator be bounded since $||Af|| \leq \sup\{x \in \Omega\} ||f||$ and $\Omega$ is bounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x$ is not a constant here, it is meant to denote the function $x\mapsto x$, and $xf$ is the function $x\mapsto xf(x)$. You're mapping functions to functions (technically, equivalence classes of functions to equivalence classes of functions). The question you need to answer is: Which functions are mapped to the zero function $x\mapsto 0$?

So the question becomes: for which functions $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is the function $xf$ equivalent to the zero function (equivalence meaning almost everywhere equality). That is, which functions satisfy $x f(x)=0$ for almost all $x\in\Omega$? You will find that they need to satisfy $f(x)=0$ for almost all $x\in \Omega$. Which makes $f$ equivalent to the zero function. And since we only care about equivalence classes, the kernel is $\{0\}$ ($0$ denoting the equivalence class of the zero function).

Comment: I believe everything you have written. However, I'm not sure why I would be interested in the mapping $x \mapsto xf(x)$ here. If I want to know what functions $f$ satisfy the differential equation $f_t(t,x) + xf(t,x) = 0$ for example, wouldn't I be concerned with the operators that map $f$?

Comment: The solution set of that equation is the kernel of the operator $f\mapsto \partial_t f+xf$. That's why you would be interested in operators on function spaces. Linear equations are described by linear maps, and studying linear maps allows us to study the solutions of linear equations. Now replace linear equations by linear differential equations and linear maps by linear operators on function spaces, and it's essentially the same, just with a harder theory behind it.